# How to set up use of camera on Android with OpenCV + Qt5

Tags: android, c++, qt, opencv

There are numerous questions like this around here, the Qt sites and the OpenCV sites, but none of them quite match my case. (And a lot are unanswered anyway.)

I'm using OpenCV for Android 2.4.6 (the prebuilt version downloadable from the official site)
to build a native App for Android (4.1.2) on a Samsung Galaxy Note 2 with Qt 5.0.1 for Android
(using QtCreator 2.7.2) on a x86_64 Linux host.

I've linked against the libraries in the ../sdk/native/libs/armeabi-v7a folder. (I haven't built OpenCV from source, I'm just using what was in the downloaded package). This includes a libopencv_androidcam.a library. (And I've also tried the libnative_camera_r4.1.1.so shared lib.)
I've also downloaded the market app "OpenCV Manager".

The sample .apks from the samples directory work on my phone, but I haven't tried to build them on my own, as I don't have a Java development environment set up.

Starting my application, which contains a `cv::VideoCapture inputCapture(CV_CAM_ANDROID);` statement, I get the following error and no camera input:

```
E/OpenCV::camera(15299): CameraWrapperConnector::connectToLib ERROR: cannot dlopen camera wrapper library
E/OpenCV::camera(15299): Native_camera returned opening error: 4
```

My questions:

- Should this work? I have seen a lot
  of bug reports, but all with older
  OpenCV versions and newer/older
  Android versions. Bonus points if it
  has been seen working on this phone
  model.
- Should this work out of the box with the downloaded OpenCV Android SDK? Or do I need to build OpenCV from source with some special options? (Which ones?)
- Do I need special library versions on the phone itself? Do I need to have root access to the device to make this work?
- Are there any "known to be working" Andoid examples using native code instead of Java?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: "I don't have a Java development environment set up" - Then how are you intending to do Android development as Java is required even for primarily native (C/C++) apps?

Comment: Qt5 handles the generation of the minimal Java program automagically. This might also be part of the problem.

Comment: i think you have to use "CV_CAP_ANDROID".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll repeat the answer I got from user @Moster at http://answers.opencv.org here:

> Copy libnative_camera_r4.1.1.so from the folder
>   /sdk/native/libs/armeabi-v7a to your Qt project's folder
>   /android/libs/armeabi-v7a. Make sure you have also allowed the camera
>   in the android_manifest in the Qt creator. Maybe all this helps

This indeed works. While I already mentioned the camera permissions in the Manifest.xml (or rather the Qt project settings), copying the shared lib to the project directory did the trick.

Seems like it's found and linked during build, but not copied to the device from its original location.
Neither the "Copy local Qt libs to device" in the deploy settings (Qt libs only?) nor the OpenCV Manager App (only loads the right libs when called directly from the Java code?) helped before.

Comment: There is no longer any `libnative_camera` in the current (3.0 + ) version of OpenCv. I wonder, was this feature dropped, or was it moved elsewhere?

Comment: Did you succeed to open camera with opencv 3.0 ?